# django - newest - first steps, weird error

Tags: django, django-models

I'm a starting with Django and already stuck with a problem:

I created this models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
# Create your models here.

class Receta(models.Model):
    receta_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.receta_text

class Ingredientes(models.Model):
    receta = models.ForeignKey(Receta)
    ingrediente_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    calorias = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    hidratos = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.ingrediente_text
```

However, I have the following error: Any Idea what the error could be??

PD: I include the full proccess followed as sugested in the django tutorial

Thanks

```
rcastillo135@Michinin:~/django_learn/nutritest$ python manage.py sql recetas
    BEGIN;
    CREATE TABLE "recetas_receta" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "receta_text" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL
    )
    ;
    CREATE TABLE "recetas_ingredientes" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "receta_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "recetas_receta" ("id"),
        "ingrediente_text" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        "calorias" real NOT NULL,
        "hidratos" real NOT NULL
    )
    ;

    COMMIT;
    rcastillo135@Michinin:~/django_learn/nutritest$ python manage.py validate
    0 errors found
    rcastillo135@Michinin:~/django_learn/nutritest$ python manage.py syncdb
    Creating tables ...
    Installing custom SQL ...
    Installing indexes ...
    Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
    rcastillo135@Michinin:~/django_learn/nutritest$ python manage.py shell
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
    [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    (InteractiveConsole)
    >>> from recetas.models import Receta,Ingredientes
    >>> p=Receta.objects.get(id=1)
    >>> p
    <Receta: Pollo>
    >>> p.ingredientes_set.all()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 71, in __repr__
        data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 96, in __iter__
        self._fetch_all()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
        self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
        for row in compiler.results_iter():
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
        for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 781, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
        return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
        six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 450, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    OperationalError: no such column: recetas_ingredientes.receta_id
    >>>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: did you run `./manage.py syncdb`?, if yes, did you add some field to your models after syncdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You presumably created your models and ran `syncdb` originally before adding the `receta` ForeignKey. `syncdb` doesn't modify tables that are already created. Since you're just experimenting, you can drop the db tables you already have and run `syncdb` again to recreate them from scratch.

You can use the third-party South project to manage db migrations for you - a version of this functionality will be included in Django 1.7 to be released during 2014.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. After a deeper analysis I found the error was I created the tables in the db and after that, modified my models. So that, in the database there was created right tables with wrong columns. That's way everything crashes. To investigate what is inside the database I used sqlite3 to open database, show tables, show columns and drop tables. Finally, after dropping wrong created tables, I repeated the process again and now is working fine.